# SQL working out above limit of a number

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I am looking to write a piece of SQL that would know when a meter passes the (through the Zero)TTZ for example a 4 digit meter 9999 is the max and after which it resets it self to 0 then 1 etc, what I want to know is whats the best way to identify this in a derived column?

My initial idea was was to use a case statement against the value of 9999 and if so then use a flag as 1 but the problem lies if there is more TTZ over time.

where meterread is the field where the 4 digit no. is held up to 9999.
Ideally I would want a derived column to separate each TTZ and know where to count if I were to do some windows function like running sum over() order by etc

Sorry its not in a great detail with the sql but just wanted to get the idea across

In this example the StartRead goes from 9889 to 449

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result as text .

Comment: You could use a trigger that fires when the inserted value is less than the current (deleted) value... When it's triggered write the date and time to a column to record the last time it happened, or just write a zero / one if all you want is to know if last update was the rollover or not

Comment: @CharlesBretana I think you mean greater than the treshold value.

Comment: This remember me about the [pac man 256](http://pacman.wikia.com/wiki/Map_256_Glitch) overflow error

Comment: @Juan,  No, if it rolls over the inserted value will be zero, and the last(Current/Deleted) value will be 9999, right?

Comment: if you assume it can never go down, then then only way it can have a lower value is by lapping around, therefore you need to select the records where the previously logged record was a higher number, then the count of these records is the count of how many times it went around the clock.

Comment: do a self join on a.id = b.id + 1 and a.val < b .val

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Create a computed column with meterserial % 10000

```
CREATE Table Meter 
(
Meterserial Int,
Metereaddate datetime,
meterread int,
met4digit as meterserial%1000
)
```

Comment: what does the %1000 at the end do?

Comment: Modulo 1000. I.e return the 3 last digits of an integer.

Comment: I mean 10000, Your example is different now, can you explain the logic of how 9889 will transform to 448?

Comment: it would be energy consumption over a period of time, if consumption is not read and goes over 9999 then the read should be the difference from the previous no. to the new no.